# creational pattern for instances depending on multiple subclass instances

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have a problem, for that I was not able to identify a suitable design pattern.

I want to create instances depending on a given type that has been passed to a factory method. What I am doing until now is the following:

```
T create(SuperType x) {
  if (x instanceof SubType1) {
    // do some stuff and return a new SubType extends T
  } else if (x instanceof SubType2) {
    // do some stuff and return a new SubType extends T
  } else if ...

  } else {
    throw new UnSupportedOperationException("nothing defined for " + x);
  }
}
```

It seems not to be best pratice for me.

Has anybody an idea how to solve this in a better way?

EDIT: The class I am receiving is not created by my self it is an instance of http://wala.sourceforge.net/javadocs/trunk/com/ibm/wala/ssa/SSAInstruction.html which has several subclasses for which I am  creating new instances depending on the type that is passed.

Comment: Does each subtype passed match exactly one return type?

Comment: No, it depends on several parameters either in the object itself or some programm state...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In object oriented programming, switching on a type is usually implemented with polymorphism, either by moving the create method into `SuperType` (where it can be overridden for each `Subtype`) or through the [visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern).

Edit: If you can't change the class, polymorphism is out. But fortunately, the class appears to support the visitor pattern (see it's `visit()` method), so you can still use that.

Comment: But to use polymorphism I have to cast to the actual subtype what I don't want to.

Comment: No, polymorphism does not require a cast.

Comment: Sorry, but when I have a method `create(SuperType)` and `create(SubType)` (`SubType extends SubType`) and you call it with `SuperType x=...; object.create(x);` the first method will be called always...

Comment: ok I'll see what I can do with the visitor pattern, though I never understood it really...

Comment: ok it kind of worked but I don't like the code I produces. But I think there is no way to do it better...